# HDMI outputs appears as “unavailable”, but running aplay command, it plays!

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

HDMI outputs appears as “unavailable”, but running aplay command, it plays!

Motherboard: AMD Rs780
System version:

```
uname -a
Linux UBUNTU-2020 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On pavucontrol => Configuration, all HDMI outputs appear as “(unavailable)”

Listing the HW Devices:

```
aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

If I run this command, the sound flows through HDMI!

```
aplay -D plughw:1,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

This command also works:

```
speaker-test --channels 2 --rate 48000 --device hw:1,3
```

I’ve tried to change /etc/asound.conf like this:

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.pcm.device 3
```

The HDMI then appears as an output device, but no sound. If I run the aplay command again, it does not play anymore:

```
aplay -D plughw:1,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
aplay: main:830: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title and the solution in the answer. Please write your own answer by clicking the button below. After the required wait time accept your answer as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark ✔ and make it turn green ✅.

Comment: Found the solution here: https://gist.github.com/bassmanitram/495fd35b76083f0c4a79777b8ab470fd

Comment: This is the comment area. Please click the button below to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

## There is a script

According to OP [Gustavo Moeira's](https://askubuntu.com/users/1107755/gustavo-moreira) comment above, there is a script available to workaround this issue. The script is available at:

https://gist.github.com/bassmanitram/495fd35b76083f0c4a79777b8ab470fd

I have no idea what this script does. As with anything on the Internet, one should understand and verify if it is safe before using it.

Hope this helps others with this problem